# Fit 1185px (Non Responsive) Mark-Up on all Mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a Mark-Up with width of 1185px (Non Responsive). How to fit this width on all mobile and tablets?
It works if i change the width to 960px but it is not fitting with 1185px.
Please help!

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>TV2V</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
</head>
<body>

    <div style="background:red; width:1185px; height:200px; margin:auto;">        
        Testing
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's non responsive it's never gong to fit on all mobile and tablets.

Comment: This is controllable by using the view-port metatag. (http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design). But it is not working if width exceeds 960px.

Comment: This thing needs to be sorted out without using media queries

Comment: `<div style="background:red; width:1185px; height:200px; margin:auto;">        
        Testing
    </div>` your div tag has fixed width set on it - so even on mobile it will try to take up that width space. it cannot be responsive if you have fixed widths like that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a simple media query in css. For example these typicals:

```
    /* xs */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){

}
/* sm */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){

}
/* md */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){

}
/* lg */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){

}
```

And check please [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) article about it.

Comment: Thanks,but i can't use media queries. This thing needs to be sorted out without using media queries.

Comment: Oh i see. One possible way to tweak the size with javascript. you should ask the window size , then modify the style attribute of your div. (If you can use some javascript).

Or different way the same what the bootsrap use for big table-s as responsive. (put the table into a div and its gonna scrolalble but overflow hidden, and show some scrollbar for it)

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1185px, initial-scale=1">
```

put above inside

```
<head></head>
```

and aren't you missing the opening-tag for

```
<head>
```

and

```
<html>
```